# XSLT 1.0 : move element to the bottom of the parent and sort them

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to move some elements to the bottom of their parent and order them by an attribute "messageid"

Here is the XML

```
<Root>
<parent>
<child/>
<child2 messageid="8"/>
<child/>
<child2 messageid="5"/>
<child/>
<child2 messageid="7"/>
</parent>
</Root>
```

Here is the wanted XML Output

```
<Root>
<parent>
<child/>
<child/>
<child/>
<child2 messageid="5"/>
<child2 messageid="7"/>
<child2 messageid="8"/>
</parent>
</Root>
```

I think I need to use a xsl:copy but I don't know how to do it. Thanks for the help

Comment: Which ones should be at the bottom? The elements child2 or all the ones with a messageid attribute? Shall only the ones on the bottom be sorted?

Comment: Sorry, yes all the child2 element must be at the bottom and they must be sorted by messageid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="parent">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::child2)]" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="child2">
        <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="@messageid" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked only if i remove the mode=number in the sort :)

Comment: @CRT Right, the attribute should be called `data-type` - fixed that. Note that without, it will do a text sort, e.g. "10" is considered less than "2".

Comment: arf ok but it is not good than 10 is consided less than 2. Is there a way to fix this ? What do you mean by should be called data-type ?

Comment: @CRT As I said, I edited my answer, it's all right there (look at the `xsl:sort`).

Answer (score 1):

It may be even easier.
Using a slightly modified identity template on the `parent` nodes seems to do the job:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <!-- slightly modified identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="parent">
    <xsl:copy> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
        <xsl:sort select="@messageid"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy> 
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*"> 
    <xsl:copy> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy> 
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```